# mdadm arrays referencing the same devices

Tags: mdadm

I've a software RAID setup for one of my servers. Now there are two arrays that reference the same devices (md126/md127 - see below) where one of them is marked inactive.

I want to understand what the best way is to remove the inactive one (md127) without affecting the active array (md126). I've already commented out md127 in /etc/mdadm.conf but the device persists a reboot.

Usually I would run `mdadm --zero-superblock` to properly cleanup a device but in this case I'm afraid this would affect the running array.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md122 : active raid6 sdaj[4] sdak[7] sdag[1] sdal[8] sdai[3] sdaf[5] sdah[2] sdae[0] sdab[6]
  27348210176 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [9/9] [UUUUUUUUU]

md123 : active raid6 sdo[2] sdac[7] sdaa[6] sdad[8] sdy[1] sdx[4] sdz[5] sdt[0] sdm[3]
  27348210176 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [9/9] [UUUUUUUUU]

md124 : active raid6 sdw[6] sds[7] sdn[2] sdv[5] sdr[3] sdq[8] sdu[4] sdp[1] sdl[0]
  27348210176 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [9/9] [UUUUUUUUU]

md125 : active raid6 sdi[5] sdk[8] sdj[6] sdd[3] sdf[4] sde[0] sdh[2] sdg[1] sdc[7]
  27348210176 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [9/9] [UUUUUUUUU]

md126 : active raid1 sda[1] sdb[0]
  111357952 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/2] [UU]

md127 : inactive sda[1](S) sdb[0](S)
  6306 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>



[root@localhost ~]# tail -1 /etc/mdadm.conf
#ARRAY /dev/md/imsm0 UUID=c8cf93ff:254853ef:d4f8137c:23b0338a
```

Comment: imsm so it's fakeraid? in that case it's normal.

Comment: @frostschutz. So I assume because this is Intel fakeraid it cannot be suppressed? The issue I have is that our monitoring system expects a status for any mdraid device and this one doesn't have one.